# Word for splitting field of irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I need to translate some german algebra lecture notes, and I'm wondering if there is a specific english word for a splitting field $L/K$ of an *irreducible* polynomial $f \in K[X]$. In german, $L$ is then called the **Stammkörper von $f$**. I don't mean simple extension here.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. I would probably just say something like, "$L/K$ is the splitting field of the irreducible polynomial $f\in K[x]$" i.e. I would just explicitly indicate irreducibility of $f$.

Comment: Stammkörper=Zerfällungskörper=splitting field, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiDxKGBrJ7uAhVIw4sKHYYiAXEQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathematik.uni-kl.de%2F~gathmann%2Fclass%2Falgebra-2010%2Falgebra-2010-c4.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1WFmVqIDk1wvYjfQpFx_bN).